# Unusual animateWithDuration behaviour in viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, animation

I'm experiencing some unusual behaviour when performing an animated transform on a `UIImageView`. The code in the method below makes the image appear like it's rocking from side-to-side:

```
-(void) shakeAnimation
{
    float degrees = 30; //the value in degrees
    imgShake.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.20f delay:0 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{
        imgShake.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees*M_PI/180);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imgShake.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1*M_PI/180);
        NSLog(@"Shake finished");
    }];
}
```

The problem comes with where i call the method. If i call the method in `viewDidAppear` the animation seems to work perfectly...but for other reasons i need to call it in `viewDidLoad`. When i call the method from `viewDidLoad` the animation functions but not at the speed specified by `animateWithDuration`. It's much slower, probably `0.70f`. Is there something i could be missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never need to call it in `viewDidLoad`. That's simply wrong and it won't work. Move the code into `viewDidAppear`. If you have reasons to put it into `viewDidLoad`, fix the reasons!

EDIT: You never know when `viewDidLoad` is called - it can even be called multiple times for one controller. Usually the problem with slow animations is caused by a collision between two animations. For example, if your controller is animated to the screen by a `UINavigationController`, your animation will collide with the "push" animation and they will be slow. That's why you are supposed to use `viewDidAppear` because when this method is called you know that the controller is displayed and the "appear" animation has ended.

Comment: Can you explain what the problems with calling a method in `viewDidLoad` is? Also, why there seems to be a problem with the animation duration?

Answer (score 0):

Call the method using some delay.

`[self performSelector:@selector(shakeAnimation) withObject: afterDelay:2.0]`